# How do I reduce width of one face and maintain geometry

Tags: edit-mode

I am modelling steps used by passengers to board a float plane.
The first 'step' is more of a small platform with the rear edge is narrower than the front edge.
I have created the first step with a cube and added front legs and angled 'strengthener' with an extra edge and then select the rear face and use SCALE on the Y axis to make the rear width less than the front.
Problem is the geometry around the two legs and angled strengthener is not maintained.
How do I do it?
Here is an image of the real object followed by an image of the object in blender and the blender file is also attached.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing cut this vertical edge with the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>A</kbd> to cut orthogonally, <kbd>C</kbd> to cut through):

[image]

Also create this edge loop with the knife:

[image]

Now you can give your object a *Mirror* modifier:

[image]

If the front needs to keep its length, put the 3D cursor at the bottom right, choose 3D Cursor as *Transform Pivot Point*:

[image]

Then in top view use the *Shear* tool on the (view) Y axis (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>)::

[image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots. I want both sides done so do I (somehow) 'mirror'? Also I note that the last step (shear?) causes the front to increase in length. Would it be easier to start from 'scratch' (single mesh cube)? I haven't spent much time on it so far so don't mind starting again from 'scratch'.

Comment: Yes you need to use the Mirror modifier, as for the length, see my edit

Comment: I have 'hit the wall' with the first step (have never used the knife tool' before. I press the K key, position the cursor on the bottom vertice, then press A (a vertical line shows), then click on the top edge where the line intersects and press C then ENTER to complete but I only get an edge between the vertices appear. Tried other 'combinations' of key presses etc but couldn't get any better.

Comment: You need to press KAC then click on the bottom vertex, then top vertex, then Enter to validate

Comment: Thanks, Yes that works but it is getting late (for me) and I will have to press on with the other steps later.

Comment: Can't sleep so on I go. I had trouble at first getting the edge on the top face square even though I (thought I) selected the far edge where the 'help' line intersected.   Maybe I wasn't watching closely enough or there is a 'trick' when using the knife tool (new to me). Anyway that disclosed that the intersection of the 'brace' with the 'leg was 2mm different between opposite sides so I fixed that (by dragging the relevant vertice).

Comment: Hard to help through the Stack Exchange comments, you can join a Discord if you want to chat and share your screen

Comment: all good now thanks